# Nginx config rewrite rule combination

Tags: .htaccess, url, nginx, url-rewriting, config

So I have these 2 rules for url rewrites.

```
location ~ /details {
rewrite ^/details/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)_(.*).html$ /site/$4.$5.html permanent;
rewrite ^/details/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)_(.*)_(.*).html$ /site/$4.$5.$6.html permanent;
}
```

But for some reason the first one on its own works just fine but the second one will not pick up.

Is there a way I could combine these 2 rules into 1?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try switching the order:

```
location ~ /details {
  rewrite ^/details/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)_(.*)_(.*).html$ /site/$4.$5.$6.html permanent;
  rewrite ^/details/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)_(.*).html$ /site/$4.$5.html permanent;
}
```

Because `(.*)` matches everything, it'll gobble up everything including `_` characters, so your first regex matches everything the second one does and thus the second rule never gets reached.